# Ajax parameters passed return undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I am posting an Ajax call to a PHP function but all the data passed is "UNDEFINED". When I debugged the JQuery, the value seems work.  The undefined is at server side. PHP side.

```
$('.js-checkout-shipping-submit').on('click', function(e) {

$.ajax({
  // Change the URL to the right one
  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout/updateShippingAddress',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'firstName:' + $(' .js-checkout-firstName').val() +
        ',lastName:' + $('.js-checkout-lastName').val() +
        ',address:' + $('.js-checkout-address').val() +
        ',zipcode:' + $('.js-checkout-zipcode').val()  ,
  success: function(data) {

    if(data['status'] === "pass"){
      console.log("success");
    }

    if(data['status'] === "fail") {
      console.log("fail");
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
  }
});

e.preventDefault();

});

 public function updateShippingAddress(){

    $firstName=$this->request->post['firstName'];
    $lastName=$this->request->post['lastName'];
    $address=$this->request->post['address'];
    $zipCode=$this->request->post['zipcode'];
}
```

Comment: means Where You Get Error? While sending thru ajax OR receiving thru php?

Comment: Where u get Undefined ? on which line of aja

Comment: I'm wonder why you are posting with the JSON data type.  Shouldn't this just be a normal post?  Is your PHP server parsing JSON?  It looks like you're just expecting normal post parameters.

Comment: @jfriend00 `dataType` is for the expected encoding from the server, but the actual issue is the malformed request parameters. `data` is just a string but it should be an object to which the [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) could be applied(internal implementation) to encode it to correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting the JSON object as string, please try this

```
data: { // making the data to become object
   firstName : $('.js-checkout-firstName').val(),
   lastName : $('.js-checkout-lastName').val(),
   address : $('.js-checkout-address').val(),
   zipcode : $('.js-checkout-zipcode').val()
 },
 success: function(data) {
 ...
```

If you are getting `undefined` as value of post params, maybe there is jQuery selector problem.

Try to log `$('.js-checkout-firstName').val()` and see what you get and make shre an Input is present with class `.js-checkout-firstName`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your request parameter in json format for ajax.
so your data parameter value is be like,

`data: {'firstName' : $('.js-checkout-firstName').val(),'lastName' : $('.js-checkout-lastName').val(),'address' : $('.js-checkout-address').val(),'zipcode' : $('.js-checkout-zipcode').val()},
success: function(data) {`